# Can't update custom module

Tags: 7, updating

I need to add some tables to the database in a new module version. I created a hook_update function:

```
function bundles_update_7000()
{
    ...
}
```

But for some reason my module is missing in the updates list in the admin interface. When I run:

```
drush pm-update bundles
```

it writes: "No code updates available."

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you done `drush cc all` to make extra sure that Drupal knows that new function has popped up?

Comment: @WestonWedding I ran it, but "drush pm-update bundles" returns the same.

Comment: And it's in bundles.install?

Comment: @WestonWedding yes. Almost identical code in another module worked.

Comment: Very strange.  I'll keep asking the dumb questions, I guess:  The module is enabled and installed?

Comment: If you can run a quick SQL query, what is the result of ```SELECT name, schema_version FROM `system` WHERE name = 'bundles'```  ?  Maybe it already ran.

Comment: @WestonWedding I ran `drush pm-list`, it is there: "Bundles (bundles)                                            Module  Enabled"

Comment: @WestonWedding schema_version = 0

Comment: Aside: unless your update hook is part of an upgrade for D6 -> D7, it's conventional to start at `7100` ([the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) have more details)

Comment: @Clive ok, I changed the function name to bundles_update_7100

Comment: @Clive Can you tell me, why this update is missing in admin listing for updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run drush updb, not drush pm-update. And you don't specify the module name.  So just:

```
drush updb
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked after changing the function name and running your command.